# How to handle AddHoc profile expiration

Tags: xcode, provisioning

Just want to clarify what to do when my AddHoc profile expires later this month. Is this the best way to update my distribution?

1. When the profile expires, go to the Developer Portal's Provisioning Profiles and click Renew.
2. Download the AddHOc profile
3. Email the new profile to my client
4. Have my client drag the new profile to the iTunes icon in the Dock of one of his Macs.
5. Have my client then synch each of his iPads in iTunes.

This is the first time I am doing this and would like for it to go smoothly. As I understand the process, there is no need to give them a new app archive. They just need the new provisioning profile.

Is the old profile in iTunes and on the iPads overwritten, or do they have to be deleted?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the process. I'd recommend looking into [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com) to ease your working with external testers.  They simplify the process of distributing profiles and builds.

Comment: Thanks Richard. TestFlight looks to be exactly what I need.